# Polymorphic custom serialization strategy?

Tags: kotlinx.serialization

I'm having a really difficult time working this out. I have a polymorphic JSON structure that I want to parse and flatten. Basically this:

```
{
  "objectType": "type",
  "data": {...}
}
```

And the `data` object changes depending on type. What I would like to achieve is have a possibility to parse this json directly into a structure which only contains fields in `data` object. Preferably it should work on polymorphic principle like this:

```
@Serializable
@JsonClassDiscriminator("type")
abstract class Thing(val type: String)

@Serializable
@SerialName("image")
data class Image(val url: String, val width: Int, val height: Int): Thing("image")

val string = """
{
  "type": "image",
  "data": {
    "url": "..",
    "width": 140,
    "height": 250
  }
}
"""

println(Json.decodeFromString<Image>(string)))
```

I know it can be easily done by unwrapping manually but the api I'm interacting with has every single type (hundreds of them) inheriting from that `Thing` type and unwrapping it manually each time and writing separate implementation for all of them seems tedious and I would rather spent a week trying to figure out a generic solution for all.

The easiest way would be to implement a custom serializer for `Thing` like in [this](https://medium.com/transferwise-engineering/how-to-master-polymorphism-and-custom-serializers-in-kotlinx-serialization-7190da0f42aa) article but it must be terribly outdated cause I couldn't get that approach to work.

Comment: If by "unwrapping manually" you mean depending on `objectType` deserializing `data` differently, that _is_ polymorphic deserialization. No real way around it. You can store the type discriminator (seemingly `objectType` in the JSON output in the API you are using) elsewhere, but it's necessary information.

Comment: At a glance, you can probably create a `Thing<TData>` class with a `TData` field. For all "things" you then create a simple oneliner extending class, and you create serializable types for `TData`. You should then register all of these classes for polymorphic serialization, or, make the base `Thing` sealed.

Comment: Yeah I know. That's what I'm doing right now. Each class just extends from `Thing` and the actual data is stored inside. So each class is still contained in an envelope and there is no other way around it. Bummer. I thought I could do something like an envelope unwrapper converter in retrofit.

Comment: Default poly serialization adds a `type` field to the object itself. Not in a wrapper. You could avoid the need for the `Thing` wrapper by writing a custom JSON-specific serializer which redirects to a poly serializer for your `data` type and transforms the JSON prior to deserializing and after serialization.